# disable graphql queries other than crud in strapi v4

Tags: api, graphql, strapi

I want to create a public facing API to fetch product, category etc. using `strapi v4` `graphql` plugin. 
I can disable some crud queries in the `src/index.js` file using the example [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#customization).

However I don't know how to disable the queries and mutations of things that are not part of `shadowCRUD` such as `uploadFile`, `uploadFolder`, `i18Nlocale`, `usersPermissions`, `register`, `login` etc.

[image: some example]

How can I achieve this in `strapi v4` (v4.3.4 as of right now)

Comment: Remove users-permissions package, if you're not using it.

Answer (score 3):

```
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::users-permissions.role').disableQueries();
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::i18n.locale').disableQueries();
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::upload.folder').disableQueries();
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::upload.folder').disableMutations();
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::upload.file').disableMutations();
extensionService.shadowCRUD('plugin::upload.file').disableQueries();
```

Adding these lines did help but still some of the non-content specific mutations are there (userPermissionsUser, userPermissionsRole). Still, I think there's a much cleaner way to do this somewhere.

Comment: Also having this issue. I only want shadowCRUD for my own custom content-types not all of the built-in junk